# How do I make functions added by Tampermonkey be available in console after the script has been ran?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I made a script that among other things has a function in it:

```
function updateGUI(){
    document.getElementById("cursoft").value = getSoftware();
    document.getElementById("curver").value = getCurrentVersion();
    document.getElementById("rcycles").value = getResearchCycles();
    document.getElementById("rcycle").value = getCurrentCycle();
    document.getElementById("curproc").value = getCurrentProcess();
    document.getElementById("curact").value = getCurrentAction();
}
```

The script runs on page load just fine, but when I try to run this function after the script finishes execution it's "undefined".
How can I make it "stay" in the current scope?

Comment: try `window.updateGUI = function(){ ...`.

Comment: I am trying to do the same with https://gist.github.com/Bluscream/d6012847585326895f3660f82dff3c7a but it doesnt seem to work: ` ReferenceError: export_cookies is not defined[Weitere Informationen]`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Tampermonkey scripts are run in a separate scope. This means that to make a function available globally you'll want to do something along the following:

```
window.updateGUI = function () {...}
```

If you want to add a number of functions to the global scope, it's better to store them under a single object and address your functions through there. That helps avoid any possible collisions you might otherwise have.

```
var myFunctions = window.myFunctions = {};
myFunctions.updateGUI = function () {...};
```

After that you can simply call `myFunctions.updateGUI();`.

Answer (score 9):

A better way do to that is to grant `unsafeWindow`.

```
// @grant       unsafeWindow
```

Then create your function like this:

```
function test()
{
    console.log("test");
}
```

But also make it available in console through `unsafeWindow`:

```
if(!unsafeWindow.test)
{
    unsafeWindow.test = test;
}
```

Then you can access `test` in the console.

Comment: In TamperMonkey, scripts are run in the same context as the page's own Javascript. Hence `unsafeWindow` is exactly the same object as `window`. It only exists for compatibility with true user scripts (those handled by the browser).

Comment: Oh my god! You can't imagine how much I searched for this. Only working solution is your answer! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer to my question, but Nit's answer is superior. I will still post mine in case someone needs it.

You can add functions to global scope by adding them to a script element and appending it to body

```
var scriptElem = document.createElement('script');
scriptElem.innerHTML = 'function updateGui() { /* stuff */ }';
document.body.appendChild(scriptElem);
```