# Tampermonkey add global functions available in console

Tags: javascript, global, addeventlistener, event-listener, tampermonkey

My problem was: I could only call the function for the first time when I press Ctrl Shift I to call out the console. After that, the function won't work.

I faced this problem a few months ago and got an answer from here
[How do I make functions added by Tampermonkey be available in console after the script has been ran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680230/how-do-i-make-functions-added-by-tampermonkey-be-available-in-console-after-the)

I did it like this and my personal PC works:

```
let myFunctions = window.myFunctions = {};

myFunctions.onKeyDown = function () {
    const keyName = event.key;
    //console.log(keyName);

    if (keyName === "Alt") {
        return;
    }

    if (event.altKey) {
        switch (keyName) {
            case 'a':
                console.log("alt a pressed");
                return
            case 's':
                console.log("alt s pressed");
                return
        }
    }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", myFunctions.onKeyDown, false);
```

And now, I faced the same problem again, in my office computer.
I used this code, exactly the same, still works for my home PC and not work for my office PC.
Tampermonkey setting exactly the same. Other functions in tampermonkey working (the scripted is inserted into the page)
I searched for other solutions. Unsafe Window does not work. Please offer help. Thank you!

Comment: Replace `window` with `unsafeWindow` or remove all `@grant` and then add `@grant none`.

Comment: not working, now my personal pc not working as well I don't know why TT